# Parsing bad CSV

Tags: parsing, io

I've got a "bad" tab separated file that I need to clean up. The problem lies in the fact that fields might have linebreaks. I think the easiest way to fix this is to replace the 'wrong' linebreaks with some sort of replacement character, say a space. now I can imagine a way to do this, if there are supposed to be n fields on a line would be (pseudocode)

```
var line = read n-1 fields ending in a tab, and then until the end of line
line.replace("\n", " ")
line.replace("\r", " ")
write line to output
```

Now these files are huge, and slurping them is not an option. Is this a reasonable approach? (I know this will trip over linebreaks in the last field, but I'm willing to live with that)
What would be a good way to read enough data? I don't care much which language it's in, but prefer .net, perl or python2 as I have runtimes for those available.

Comment: If the file is not *dreadfully* large, I'd just be doing it in Vim. If it is, then I personally would do it in Python. Your approach seems fine to me.

Comment: In the order of gigabytes. I shudder of the thought of slurping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in a really quick awk script:

```
awk -F\t '{while(NF < (numberoffields) { line=$0; getline; $0 = line $0;} print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

A Python solution:

```
csv_filename = 'foo.csv'
new_csv_filename = 'foo.fixed.csv'
num_fields = 10

with open(csv_filename, 'rU') as reader and open(new_csv_filename, 'w') as writer:
    while True:
        line = ''
        while len(line.split('\t')) < num_fields:
            line += reader.readline().replace('\n', ' ')
        writer.write(line + '\n')  # Or '\r\n' if you prefer
```

I wouldn't make the file replacement automatic; make sure you keep the original.

Comment: I don't know what you intend to do with the file, but if you intend to do further working with it which you could do in Python, there would be no need to write it. You could make it a generator (put it in a function and instead of `writer.write(...)`, `yield ...`) and work with it with the `csv` module (delimiter='\t').

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, but I just need to ship it off.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have the time to test it yesterday. This anwer looks clearly correct, yet the awk script is much more concise. If that one works for me, I'll accept it, otherwise i'll accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question, but you need a text editor program like TextWrangler (for Mac OSX). This can handle large datasets and do some pretty sophisticated search and replace.

There must be a PC equivalent program I guess.

CSV files are basically text files at the end of the day, so that's what you need to take the donkey work out of the issue.

Comment: I don't see why using a full featered text editor/IDE with regex search capabilities has any advantage over reading it programatically. TextWrangler will probably struggle on large files too (see http://faq.barebones.com/do_getanswer.php?record_id=36)

Comment: I deal with data uploads on a daily basis loading literally millions of records, and believe me this is not uncommon when dealing with flat files. However, the difference is pretty obvious. You have write, run and check the results of the program, on a file where you can't say for sure where the error lies. A text editor (simple or complex) can speed up the analysis process because the search capabilities are made for exactly this task - and you don't have to test. It just works. In some cases you may only be talking about one or two lines or error records.

Comment: Obviously I have no idea of the actual size of your dataset, or how the CSV file was created. Perhaps it was a bad script that took a selection from a database? Couldn't you fix the extraction script?